# Cocoa-Touch: How to do layouting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a view (`UIScrollView`), which loads some data, and displays various things from it in various subviews. So I have approx 10 subviews (`UIImageView, UILabel`) and I need to place them programatically considering their unpredictable contents (i.e. different height/width for the `UILabel`s depending on the text property).

From what I've read, there is no layout framework for Cocoa-touch.

What is the best way to do this?

From what I can tell, I should put the contents in the views, then start calculating coordinates based on their frames after calling their `sizeToFit` methods.

This approach is very error-prone. Is there really no other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, there are no automatic layout managers. Subclassing `UIScrollView` and overriding `layoutSubviews` is probably the right way to implement your custom algorithm. You can then call `setNeedsLayout` to do the layout.

Answer (score 3):

Layout in Cocoa is typically done with auto-resizing (using `autoresizingMask`).  You start with your view at some hard-coded initial size, say 200x200; place your subviews onto this view and set the autoresizing flags accordingly.  This view is then free to be resized to its actual size, as determined by its parent view/window.  The process is the same whether you use Interface Builder or whether you do it programmatically.

If you need a vertical stack of views you can use a table view.

If you want more complicated layout you need to implement it yourself, by overriding `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any automatic layout managers or the like.

So, I think you'll have to calculate the desired positions and sizes and update the `frame`s of your subviews manually.

EDIT: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181725/are-there-constraint-layout-managers-on-iphone-os) where Brad Larson points to an example of a custom layout manager. HTH

Answer (score -1):

You can use Interface Builder to create a view and then drag and drop elements into it.

Comment: try reading the question before answering, YES, IB works when I have static content. The question is about what's the best way to do it when the content is dynamic.